# Reading from XML error

Tags: c#, xml, user-controls, xmlnode

### **I've got maybe a simple question for you, but Im stuck with this one.**

So, I have an application, which has multiple userControls, inherited from one class. I can drag them to a panel, and resize them. I have save and open features for userControl position/size saving/loading from XML file. Lately I improved it with a feature which lets you to add additional stuff to them in code, then save it with the rest of primary parameters.

Here's an example:[image: XML]
Basically it detects if any additional parameters have been added and save them under `<Parameters>` tag.

Here's an example of userControl code I added some stuff to:[image: Usercontrol1]

Saving went well, but I'm stuck at loading part. I tried to test it at first by writing any discovered parameters to richTextBox, to see if it reads any data at all.
I thought, that it should work by detecting userControls first, then to look for parameters in each userControl.

I got this error:[image: debug]

As you can see below, the program reads the XML, but stops at the point, where richTextBox needs to be filled. It doesn't happen, because in the list, which should contain both parameters, there is just one parameter, kind of a hybrid.

I'm confused. Any advice?

---

*Developer in training*

Comment: Use the debugger to see which object is null; it is one of: richTextBox1, pm, pm.Name, or pm.Value.

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) maybe it helps you.

Comment: can you post actual code and not a screen shot.. also what is the balue of pm when you step in the code? you need to get at the `InnerText` so perhaps pm.Name.ToString() should be changed to `pm.Name.InnerText.ToString()`

Comment: I already fixed it, yes, with inner text, which I forgot to add :P

Comment: it appears you did not fix it correctly what happens if you try it with the above commented suggestion..?

Comment: I just wanted to test if it reads the xml and can find parameters at all. As it crashed I wondered if there is any problem with the reading part of the code, but the problem was that I forgot to convert inner text into variables, I just got lazy and stupid :P Now, when it spits out something logical on the textbox, I will manage to get it into right places in no time :) ... tomorrow :D my practical hours ends now, I must go. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I wanted to post an answer, but this got closed.  Change `XmlNodeList pmList = doc.SelectNodes("/root/UC/Parameters");` to `XmlNodeList pmList = xn.SelectNodes("Parameters/*");` and change `pm.Name + " - " + pm.Value` to `pm.Name + " - " + pm.InnerText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woaw, I'm so lazy :D

I forgot to convert parameters' inner texts :P

```
foreach (XmlNode pm in pmList)
                {
                    int s = int.Parse(pm["RandomParameter1"].InnerText);
                    int ss = int.Parse(pm["RandomParameter2"].InnerText);

                    richTextBox1.AppendText(pm["RandomParameter1"].ToString() + " - " + s.ToString() + "\n");
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(pm["RandomParameter1"].ToString() + " - " + ss.ToString() + "\n");

                }
```

Still need to work on parameter name output, as the result i get on textbox is:

```
System.Xml.XmlElement - 27
System.Xml.XmlElement - 10
System.Xml.XmlElement - 27
System.Xml.XmlElement - 10
System.Xml.XmlElement - 27
System.Xml.XmlElement - 10
```

Buuut, it's a start, isn't it? :D

---

Thanks for anyone who spared their time trying to fix my lazy mistake :)

Comment: You get the repeating because you are getting the `Parameter` `XmlNodeList` from the root of the doc every time (`XmlNodeList pmList = doc.SelectNodes("/root/UC/Parameters");`).  See my comment to fix it.